# "Root element is missing" when executing ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Tags: powershell, error

The following script works on all computers in my company, but doesn't work on one laptop when working from home.

The laptop can run the script in the office, not from home. The laptop in the home network can reach the site files via OneDrive on Demand and can use the SharePoint web UI.

When executing the script on the laptop from the home network, it says "Root element is missing":

Disabling the VPN, changing the DNS configuration as suggested [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIKax.png), and disabling the ipv6 as suggested [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atxQp.png), didn't help.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

```
$User = "<email address>"
$Password = "<password>"
$SiteUrl = "<site url>"
$LibraryName = "Documents"

Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $SecurePassword)
$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$ClientContext.Credentials = $Credentials
$Web = $ClientContext.Web
$List = $ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
$ClientContext.Load($Web)
$ClientContext.Load($List)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host $List.ItemCount
Write-Host $web.MasterUrl
Write-Host $Web.Description
```

**EDIT** *(I removed the old snapshot taken after executing a script slightly different from the above and added the snapshots of the script above running on both home and office networks)*

This is the output of the script when it runs in the office network:
[image]

This is the output of the script when it runs in the home network:
[image]

Comment: Hi Stenci. It looks like the screenshot of an error does not match the script you posted.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because the problem doesn't happen on my computer. I posted an old screenshot that I got during a remote session, before I was able to create a smaller script to isolate the problem. The script I posted works on my computer and fails on the other computer. But when I tested the shorter script I forgot to take the screenshot, so I posted the old one. If it really makes a difference, I can try to reproduce it again.

Comment: I think it helps to get a new screenshot or an error for the same script you posted.